# Saving cookies across requests to request headers

Tags: python, http, cookies, python-requests, http-headers

I am working on a project, and i need to log in to icloud.com using requests. I tried doing it myself but then i imported library `pyicloud` which does login for me and completes the 2fa. But when it does login i need to create hide my mails which library doesnt to and i tried to do it my self using post, and get requests. However i want to compile it and make it user friendly so the user wont need to interfere with the code, so it automatically gets cookies and puts it in request header, and this is my main problem.
This is my code

```
from pyicloud import PyiCloudService
import requests
import json

session = requests.Session()

api = PyiCloudService('mail', 'password')

# here is the 2fa and login function, but after this comment user is logged in

headers = {
'Accept': '*/*',
'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
'Accept-Language': 'pl-PL,pl;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
'Connection': 'keep-alive',
'Content-Length': '2',
'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
'Origin': 'https://www.icloud.com',
'Referer': 'https://www.icloud.com/',
'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-site',
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.64 Safari/537.36',
'sec-ch-ua': '" Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="101", "Google Chrome";v="101"',
'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"macOS"'
}

session.get('https://icloud.com/settings/')
r = session.post('https://p113-maildomainws.icloud.com/v1/hme/generate?clientBuildNumber=2215Project36&clientMasteringNumber=2215B21&clientId=8b343412-32c8-43d6-9b36-ffc417865d6e&dsid=8267218741', headers=headers, json={})
print(r.text)
```

And with manually entered cookie into the header it prints this

```
{"success":true,"timestamp":1653818738,"result":{"hme":"clones.lacks_0d@icloud.com"}}
```

And without the cookie which i want to automatically enter into the header it prints out this

```
{"reason":"Missing X-APPLE-WEBAUTH-USER cookie","error":1}
```

I tried making

```
session = requests.Session()
```

and this what another user told me to do, but this also doesnt work.

```
session.get('https://icloud.com/settings/')
```

I need to somehow get the 'cookie': 'x' into the header without me changing the headers manually, maybe something with response header.

Any help will be appriciated
Thank you, and have a nice day:)

Comment: try giving `headers` in your `session.get` instead of `session.post` in order to avoid over-writing them.

Comment: @MohitC just have done that, i get 0 response back, nothing prints and the program ends.

Comment: you mean something like this ? `session.get('https://icloud.com/settings/', headers=headers)
r = session.post('https://p113-maildomainws.icloud.com/v1/hme/generate?clientBuildNumber=2215Project36&clientMasteringNumber=2215B21&clientId=b193dc76-87e1-4d9e-9e8f-f0c1508b2a7b&dsid=8267218741', json={})
print(r.text)`

Comment: if you use `Session` then it should automatically get cookies from one request and use it in another request. But you could check server really send cookies to you. Maybe it doesn't gives you expected cookie and it may need to analyze why you don't get it. Maybe it uses JavaScript to create cookies - but `requests` can't run JavaScript. And putting manually some values may not work because often cookies are valid only by short time and you have get from server fresh cookies.